# Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setBCCaddress(List<String>)

Tags: apex, visualforce, massemailmessage

getting the error

> Method does not exist or incorrect signature:
>   [Messaging.SingleEmailMessage].setBCCaddress(List)

from the code

```
public PageReference show() 
    {
    messaging.singleemailmessage mail=new messaging.singleemailmessage();
    string[] tobcc=new string[]{'sfdccharan@gmail.com','nchnaidu12@gmail.com'};
    mail.setBCCaddress(tobcc);
    string[] tocc= new string[]{'narracharan4@gmail.com'};
    mail.setCCaddress(tocc);
    string[] to=new string[]{'charansfdc511@gmail.com'};
    mail.setTOadress(to);
    mail.setsubject('test');
    mail.setplaintextbody('Hai CharanKumar Narra');
    mail.sethtmlbody('<h1> this is an test html</h1>');
    messaging.sendemail(new messaging.singleemailmessage[]{mail});


        return null;
    }
```

Comment: check the available methods in singleemailmessage class and use the correct method names : https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm

Answer (score -1):

You should use `setBccAddresses(List<String>)` instead of `setBccAddress(List<String>)`. You are missing `es` from the end of the function name.